# Format a TimeSpan string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, format, timespan

In the code i have :

```
gvRankings.DataSource = rankings.OrderBy(rg => rg.Swimtime).Take(100).ToArray();  
gvRankings.DataBind();
```

(Swimtime here is a `TimeSpan`)

At the frontside i have

```
< asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tijd" ItemStyle-CssClass="time" HeaderStyle-CssClass="smallheader">
< ItemTemplate><%# ("Swimtime")%>< /ItemTemplate>
< /asp:TemplateField>
```

I would like to format the swimtime like `hh:mm:dd.ff` but i have (after 2 hours of trying) absolutely no idea how to do this.....

Comment: @Squall: C#.Net.  Check the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:dd\\.ff}", yourTimeSpan)`

Comment: Thanx. However, in my case what would be 'yourTimeSpan' ?  
In the code behind it is Swimtime, but how do i call it at the front ?
I know i am missing some knowledge here, learning :)

Comment: A row in the array looks like : { AthleteId = 1734, FirstName = "Jan", MiddleName = null, LastName = "Jansen", BirthYear = 1993, NationId = "NED", Club = "Kring Rotterdam", Swimtime = {00:00:53.6500000}, Date = {12-2-2011 0:00:00}, City = "Dordrecht" ... } and i would like to get the Swimtime :)

Comment: Got it to work with this :  
<%# string.Format("{0:mm\\:ss\\.ff}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Swimtime"))%>  
If there is a cleaner way let me know, but it does work

Comment: Thanks!!! I have used it to show seconds as well.  `string.Format("Paused at {0}", string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", pausePosition));`

Answer (score 4):

You could cheat and use the `Ticks` property to create a `DateTime` and format that the way you want:

```
string formatedTime = new DateTime(swimTime.Ticks).ToString("hh:mm:dd.ff");
```